# Find your pokemon - how does it work? JS

Tags: javascript

So I found this site http://pokemon.step.lv/

If you type in your name and surname, it gives you your pokemon. I was just wondering, if somebody tells me which pokemon they are, is it possible for me to figure out their name?

I don't want to use it in any bad way, I'm just really curious, I tried to find something in this code http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js but I'm just a beginner at programming in general so it's pretty difficult for me, but it also makes me more interested in it.

If anyone is bored enough to try to help me, please just take a look

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how many pokemon there are. But I know there are fewer pokemon (men)? than there are names.

There's something called the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) that states, essentially, if you have n pigeons, and n-1 pigeonholes, each pigeon can't have its own hole. It's the same thing with names. Since there are more names than there are pokemon, there must be people who share the same pokemon. Thus, the answer is no, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is an array of pokemons. Server side script calculates hash-code from your name and gets an element from this array according to this hashcode. An arbitrary logic can be applied here, to generate array index from this hashcode.